# Where are S3/Redshift/Lambda Logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a Lambda, that copies data from Redshift to S3.

I am trying to find the logs in CloudWatch when I manually trigger the Lambda. I click logs and search under "log groups" and cannot see these.

I have enabled logs on Redshift and S3, and assume any Lambda generated has logs.

The end goal is to set up "log groups" per service so that I can subscribe through Kinesis and send the data to Redshift.

If I try to 'create a log group' under actions, I can create '/aws-s3/test' for example, but I don't know what log stream is, or how to send all S3 logs from a particular folder to S3.

Where are the logs?

Answer (score 1):

The logs from the AWS Lambda function will be automatically created in Amazon CloudWach Logs.

However, you must ensure that the Lambda function has **permission to use CloudWatch Logs**.

This is normally done by assigning the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy to the AIM Role used by the Lambda function. It contains the permissions:

- `logs:CreateLogStream`
- `logs:PutLogEvents`

They will allow the Lambda function to create the log entries.

See: [AWS Lambda Execution Role - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)

Comment: Thanks! It is working well. The S3 logs are in the default bucket. Redshift cannot be sent to CloudWatch apparently so having a separate process for that.